# How to customize PayPal Screen?

Tags: ios, customization, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PaylPal REST API. I need to customise its screens as my app have.

**Just like:**

Change topBar instead of default in PayPal Screen.

Change the Cancel button with customised Back button etc.

Is it possible to do it?
I read on developer site of PayPal and here also but i didn't found anything related to my question.

Any help or suggestion will help me a lot and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this can be customized in your Paypal control panel. On the `Profile` tab, select `My Selling Tools`, then click `Update` next to `Custom Payment Pages`. From here you have the option of modifying the template to include your logo, additional text, and more.

Other options under `My Selling Tools` can be used to modify how payment appears on credit card statements, email responses after a purchase, sales tax and more.

A more detailed explanation is available [here](https://madefreshly.com/blog/howto/customize-paypal-checkout/)

Comment: Thanks Andy... 
But i think your suggestion is helpful for WebSite not for Mobile App...
I need to customise Views for iOS mobile app.
Is there anything for it.??...